# Need help routing Cisco network- IP routing

Tags: networking, cisco, routing, ip, tcpip

[image: network diagram]

In the above network, can you help me configure routes so the computers on the left can see the computers on the right, and vice versa?

I know the syntax of the command is `ip route {network address} {subnet mask} {default gateway}`, but for some reason I'm still not getting anywhere.

Comment: This seems like a homework question...yes/no?

Comment: You show the gateway addresses that the computers are using but you don't show those gateway addresses anywhere. Presumably they're configured on the appropriate switch VLAN interface and you've enabled ip routing on the switches? Can you post your switch and router configs?

Answer (score 1):

in looking where are the default GWs?  you don't show what devices your GW live on.

assuming that 4.2.0.1 and 4.0.0.1 are both on 1841-1 and 4.2.40.1 and 4.2.32.1 are both on 1841-2

If those IPs don't exist you need to change the GW on the PC to mach the interfaces on the 1841s

for example pc0 and pc1 would need to have GW 4.2.0.4 as that is the ip of interface f0/0 in in 1841-1

1841-1
  needs to route 4.2.32.0/21 and 4.2.40.0/23 to 4.2.42.2

```
 ip route 4.2.32.0 255.255.248.0 4.2.42.2
 ip route 4.2.40.0 255.255.254.0 4.2.42.2
```

1841-2 
 needs to route 4.0.0.0/15 and 4.2.0.0/19 to  4.2.42.1

```
 ip route 4.0.0.0 255.254.0.0 4.2.42.1
 ip route 4.2.0.0 255.255.224.0 4.2.42.1
```

you shouldn't need to make routing changes on the PCS, as their default route should work.  This also assumes all static routing, and not running any routing protocols.